# javascript if conditional: object exists and has a value appended

Tags: javascript, syntax, conditional-statements

Getting an 'Invalid left-hand side in assignment' error in my console. Am I missing syntax here?

```
if ($images[next] && images[next].loaded = false){
    //stuff
}
```

Each condition passes on it's own, but fail when combined.

Comment: `mages[next].loaded == false`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Won't work if `images[next]` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a single `=` means you're assigning a value to a variable. For comparisons, use `==` or `===` for strict equality.

Answer (score 1):

Use double equals for comparison. Alternatively, you could just write:

```
var item = $images[next];
if (item && !item.loaded){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
if ($images[next] && $images[next].loaded == false){
    //stuff
}
```

Or Better

```
var images = $images[next];
if (images  && images .loaded === false){
    //stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As everybody already told you, you should be using `==` (or `===`) for comparison. What caused the error is that the assignment operator `=` has a lower [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than the boolean `&&` operator, unlike `==` or any other comparison operator. So your expression was evaluated as:

```
($images[next] && images[next].loaded) = false
```

The left-hand part, in parentheses, will be either `true` or `false`. So that becomes either

```
true = false
```

or

```
false = false
```

Neither is allowed, because you can't assign anything to a boolean value (only to a variable or object property). Hence an *Invalid left-hand side in assignment* error is thrown.

When you use a proper comparison operator, the precedence rules cause it to be evaluated like this:

```
$images[next] && (images[next].loaded == false)
```

That becomes `true && true`, or `true && false`, or `false && false`, or `false && true`, then eventually just `true` or `false`, which is what an if statement expects.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a "==" instead of a "=" in the equality check would help

```
if ($images[next] && images[next].loaded == false)
{
    //stuff
}
```

For a list of the javascript comparison operators, have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Everyone'll prly say the same thing: `... .loaded = false` should be `... .loaded == false`. `=` is an assignment operator, `==` is a comparative operator..

Sometimes you'll see `if (x = someFunction())` which will run the code block as long as someFunction() doesn't return false or throw an error (as it does in your case).

Let me know if you have any questions :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators